# Julia: How to deal with special unicode characters

Tags: unicode, julia

I am working with the Distributions package which uses special unicode characters for many of the variables within types. The normal distribution, for instance, uses μ and σ. If I want to edit the standard deviation, I need to somehow type:

n.σ = 5.0

Is it possible to type these values into the repl (outside of using copy-paste)? How does one create these characters with one's keyboard?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the REPL, use LaTeX shortcuts, e.g. type `\sigma` and press tab to autocomplete. Note you need to using Julia 0.3 or higher for this to work.

Many text editors have add-ins to do something similar, e.g. https://github.com/mvoidex/UnicodeMath for SublimeText.

Comment: The full table of unicode input is available in the online version of the Julia manual at http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/unicode-input/

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 and Linux under most modern desktops you can add a Greek keyboard map and then switch between Greek and English using [[windows button]]+space. Since many Latin / English letters are derived from ancient Greek, these have analogs so S types a Sigma (σΣ), D, a delta(δΔ) etc. ετψ.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by looking up "Entering Unicode in Linux" on Google.

One can press Ctrl+Shift+u, then the 4-digit UTF-16 Hex encoding for the character. For example, σ = u03bc

Answer (score 0):

Tt is difficult to remember all the unicodes or latex shortcuts (at least for me) or search it on the web. When working with REPL or jupyter notebook, Julia has provided a simple way to do it as mentioned [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/unicode-input/):

> You can also get information on how to type a symbol by entering it in the REPL help, i.e. by typing ? and then entering the symbol in the REPL (e.g., by copy-paste from somewhere you saw the symbol).

For example:

[image]